# Memory address of the pointer of a pointer

Tags: pointers, go

In the following code:

```
func main() {
    foo := "bar"
    fooPointer := &foo
    fmt.Println(&foo, &fooPointer)
}
```

Shouldn't the memory address of `&foo` and `&fooPointer` be the same?

My understanding is that:

- `*variable` is a Pointer to the value of `variable`
- `&variable` returns the Pointer to the `variable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
`&foo` is the address of `foo`.
`&fooPointer` is the address of `fooPointer`.
The *value* of `fooPointer` is equal to `&foo`, but the *address* of `fooPointer` is something else.